# sort of special accordion like control

Tags: wpf, xaml, width, accordion, stackpanel

I have put an example link in here:
http://activeden.net/item/xml-horizontal-vertical-accordion-banner-rotator/full_screen_preview/127714?ref=premiumtemplates

I try to achieve something similar (but far more basic) with WPF.
Not the flying text stuff, only the basic navigation idea.
I tried to build it with some expander controls and a stackpanel.
What I came up with is this:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" IsTabStop="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=tabs,Mode=OneWay}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentPresenter  Content="{Binding}" />                    
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Vertical" />               
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
```

I use MVVM, so there is also a template which is applied:

```
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:TabulatorViewModel}">
    <Expander  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ExpandDirection="{Binding .direction,Mode=OneWay}" IsExpanded="{Binding .isExpanded,Mode=TwoWay}"  Header="{Binding .header,Mode=OneWay}" >
        <Expander.Style>
              <Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}">

                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource HorizontalExpanderRight}" />

                <Style.Triggers>

                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding .direction}" Value="Left">

                        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource HorizontalExpanderLeft}" />

                    </DataTrigger>

                </Style.Triggers>

            </Style>
        </Expander.Style>

        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="{Binding .seitenInhalt.Header,Mode=OneWay}"></Label>

        <TextBox Text="{Binding .seitenInhalt.Inhalt,Mode=OneWay}"></TextBox>
            <Button Content="zurück" Command="{Binding .seitenInhalt.MovePreviousCommand}" />
            <Button Content="vor" Command="{Binding .seitenInhalt.MoveNextCommand}"/>                 

        </StackPanel>
    </Expander>

</DataTemplate>
```

So, this is working, at least kind of.

two screenshots from my current project to explain the issues:
Could not post picture because of reputation points.

All Items together should use the complete width of the stackpanel, not like in the picture. Could not post picture because of reputation points.

All items should use the complete width, but the one expanded item should have a bigger width then the rest. As on the picture, but the collapsed items should use the remaining space, each by the same amount filling the gap)

Any help would be great, I hope it is possible to understand my goal / issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to use is a UniformGridPanel or WrapPanel, which will use the full width available, rather than a StackPanel which is made to use the minimum width possible.  The panel overview is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152.aspx).

Comment: The Wrap Panel only expand the last item to full width in the remaining space and also do not expand the items to the full height (at least i think so). That is not the effect i want. But thx for your answer!

Comment: Did you try UniformGridPanel?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use a `Grid` with the `Height`/`Width` of the Columns/Rows set to `*` if the item is Expanded, or `Auto` if not.

Also, if you're using a Grid in an ItemsControl, you need to set the `Grid.Row`/`Grid.Column`, and `Width`/`Height` properties on the `ContentPresenter`, not the `ItemTemplate` since the ItemTemplate in a ItemsControl is always wrapped in a `ContentPresenter`.

Comment: Hello Rachel, sounds promising, but i do not fully understand it. Can you provide me some sample xaml? What i came up with is this: sorry, didn't manage to paste it, i am new to stack overflow...

Comment: Hello again Rachel. i think your idea is great. i manage to get it to work, at least partly. Now, my problem is the following: How to change the column width from * to auto with a viewmodel binding? this is set in the columndefinition, so how do i do that? Hope you can help me on this issue too. And, what i also like to say, if i can help you in any way, just ask! i am pretty happy that you could help me with this problem!